# Can't apply styles to Ionic radio button

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to move the icon of an Ionic radio button a few pixels upwards, but I'm unable to do so.

Here's the code for reference:

```
// HTML
<ion-radio class="radio-input" mode="md" slot="start" [value]="data"></ion-radio>

// SCSS
.radio-input {
  // this contains things irrelevant to the question
}
```

The class that seems to affect the part of the button I need is `.radio-icon`, but I'm unable to affect it on the component's stylesheet. Targeting the `.radio-input` class does nothing as it affects the entire thing, not just the button.

Hiding the element and using a "fake" radio input is not an option.

What would be the correct approach here?

**Edit:** the project is running on Ionic 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ionic** components are using [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), which means you *CANNOT* apply styles or **CSS** classes directly on them like native **HTML** elements.

To do so, back to their [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/glossary#shadow) about this part, and I qoute:

> To externally style internal elements of a Shadow DOM component you must use [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) or [CSS Shadow Parts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part).

You need to take that into consideration, I don't now what exactly you wanna do, but for example:

`ion-radio` has 2 parts you can update, `mark` and `container`, you can change their styles by:

```
ion-radio::part(mark) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, targeting the container with a shadow part does the job perfectly. Thank you!