# ionic angular app does not apply ionic styles when running on android, how can i fix this

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic Angular app, and when I run it on Android, it doesn't apply the Ionic styles properly. However, when I run the app on iOS, it picks up the styles correctly. What could be causing this discrepancy, and how can I resolve it?

[This is what happen when i run on android searchBar styles is not applied and every styles including modal..etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy0jn.png)

[Every thing is fine when i run it on ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RNgG.png)

i tried this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to manipulate the styles of components you should understand how to sneak into style-sheet. **Ionic components** are using Shadow DOM (encapsulate style and markup).

You can change platform styles with variables, basically you can call [theming](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/themes). e.g;

```
    .ios {
            --ion-background-color: #222;
         }
```

or modify component parts, you should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748731/12793123).

On the other hand if you like a style from one of the platforms, you can apply to your component. For this, use **Ionic Modes** to override.

You can force components to use the mode `ios` for ios mode or `md` for material design style. E.g;

```
<ion-searchbar mode="md"></ion-searchbar>
```

Check [Platform Styles](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles) for more information.

As to third solution if you use modular system, you can select the mode for whole application like this;

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      rippleEffect: false,
      mode: 'md'
    })
  ],
  ...
})
```

Bonus to dig, [Angular View encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) .

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Ionic, and I just found out that iOS and Material Design (MD) styles do not look the same. The MD styles appeared unattractive, which is why I thought it wasn't picking up the styles.

Comment: If this answer is useful for you, mark it as an answer to help others.